# Pseudoinverse of matrix product with multiple factors

Tags: dynamical-systems, pseudoinverse

Let
$G_\mathrm{ss}(\omega)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re\{\underline{G}(j\omega)\} & \Im\{\underline{G}(j\omega)\} \\
-\Im\{\underline{G}(j\omega)\} & \Re\{\underline{G}(j\omega)\}
\end{bmatrix}$
be the steady-state system matrix of a MIMO system $G(s)$ with arbitrary number of inputs and outputs.

Is it possible to proove that following **always** holds for a series connection $G(s) = G_1(s) \, G_2(s) \, G_3(s)$ of such systems of arbitrary (but for sure compatible) size:

$
G_\mathrm{ss}^+(\omega) = (G_{1,ss}(\omega) \, G_{2,ss}(\omega) \, G_{3,ss}(\omega))^+ = G_{3,ss}^+(\omega) \, G_{2,ss}^+(\omega) \, G_{1,ss}^+(\omega)
$

$(\cdot)^+$ is the Moore Penrose inverse.